# What are the different ways to get a first-order formula that express the statement"$P$ is the $n$-th prime"

Tags: logic, prime-numbers, first-order-logic

I know that such a $2$-predicate formula exists since Enderton's have already constructed such a formula in his text on mathematical logic but it was not easy to remember so I wonder if there is other known ways to construct such a formula.

My questions is, Are there more than one way to express such a statement in FOL? If yes, give some examples to do that. I'd love to see if any of those ways (if exist) is simple enough to remember (or give an intuition that enables oneself to re-construct it)

The question can be reforumlated as: Is there a simple trick that enables us to express "$P$ is the $n$-th prime" in first order logic?

Here is the way Enderton's used to construct such a formula:

> The function whose value at $a$ is $p_a$, the $(a + l)$st prime, is 
>   representable. (Thus $p_0 = 2, p_1 = 3, р_2 = 5, p_3 = 7, p_4 = 11$, and so 
>   forth.)
>
> Proof. $p_a = b$ iff $b$ is prime and there exists some $с < b^{a^2}$, such 
>   that (i)-(iii) hold:
>
> (i) $2$ does not divide $c$.
>
> (ii) For any $q < b$ and any $r \leq b$, if $(q, r)$ is a pair of adjacent 
>   primes, then for all $j < c$,
>
> $$q_j | с \iff r^{j+1} | c$$.
>
> (iii) $b^a$ divides $с$ and $b^{a+l}$ does not. 
>   This equivalence is not obvious, but at least the relation defined 
>   by the right-hand side is representable.

Comment: What does $b_a$ stand for? I'm just a curious guy, I have no idea how to answer this.

Comment: I nearly edited but I'm not 100% certain of my edit. Shouldn't $b^{a^2}$ be $b^2$? Shouldn't $a+l$ be $a+1$ throughout? Shouldn't $b_a$ be $b^a$?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva, I've edited it. It was a typo.

Comment: What's wrong with $Q(p, n)$ where $Q$ is the $n^\text{th}$ prime relation?

Comment: @DanielV, what is the $n^{th}$ prime relation?

Comment: @DanielV: The question is about a first-order formula in the language of PA, so adding predicates is not allowed. Curiously, it can be proven that sequences of natural numbers can be encoded as single natural numbers in a way that there are formulae to extract arbitrary terms, but this is not trivial! Godel devised a way using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, which can then be used to show that any recursive function can be represented by a $Σ_1$-formula over PA. However the formula generated by this is humongous.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative way is to first prove that the number of primes $π(n)$ in the range $\{1\,..\,n-1\}$ is representable, and then "$x$ is the $n$-th prime" is represented by the formula:

> $π(x+1) = n \land π(x)+1 = n$.

Since $π(0) = 0$ and $π(n+1) = π(n) + \mathbf{1}_{prime(n)}$ for any natural $n$, and since $prime$ can be represented by a $Δ_0$-formula, we can represent this sequence $π$ by a $Σ_1$-formula using [Godel's β function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_%CE%B2_function).